# Query Mysql no Visual Studio não retorna todos os dados

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, winforms

estou com um problema no Visual Studio, onde na minha classe de acesso a banco de dados, tenho uma query que faz uma consulta no meu banco Mysql, e retorna apenas o útlimo resultado. Portanto, quanto eu efetuo o teste desta mesma query diretamente no banco de dados Mysql, usando ferramentas como PhpMyAdmin, Mysql Workbench, etc. O banco me retorna, todos os resultados, o qual deve retornar, que no caso são 29 itens.

Segue o código C# do meu método de acesso a base de dados,

```
    public DataTable ObterListadePrecos(int codigoMedico)
    {
        Mysql mysql = new Mysql();
        try
        {
            mysql.Comando.CommandText = @"select e.codigo_anatomico, em.medico as cod, e.nome, concat(g.nome, ' > ',  s.nome) as grupo, e.valor as valorCheio, t.codigo as codTabela, t.desconto,
                                    (valor - (valor * t.desconto / 100) ) as valorComDesconto,              
                                    (valor * (select case 
                                                    when desconto = 0 
                                                    then 100 
                                                    else desconto 
                                                    end) * t.usuario_convencional /100 / 100 ) as uconvencional,              
                                    (valor * (select case 
                                                    when desconto = 0 
                                                    then 100 
                                                    else desconto 
                                                    end) * t.convenio_convencional /100 / 100 ) as sconvencional,              
                                    (valor * (select case 
                                                    when desconto = 0 
                                                    then 100 
                                                    else desconto 
                                                    end) * t.usuario_master /100 / 100 ) as umaster,              
                                    (valor * (select case 
                                                    when desconto = 0 
                                                    then 100 
                                                    else desconto 
                                                    end) * t.convenio_master /100 / 100 ) as smaster
                                    from exame_medico em, exames e, subgrupo_exame s, grupo_exame g, tabela_preco t, medico m
                                    where e.codigo_subgrupo = s.codigo
                                    and em.subgrupo = s.codigo
                                    and s.grupo_codigo = g.codigo
                                    and m.med_tabela = t.codigo
                                    and em.medico = m.med_cod
                                    and m.med_cod = @CODIGO
                                    order by e.nome desc";

            mysql.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO", codigoMedico);

            return mysql.ExecutarComando();
        }
        catch(MysqlException e)
        {
            //tratamento de minha exceptions
        }
    }

Parte do código onde monto a Grid para exibição dos dados:

    gridView.DataSource = minhaClasse.ObterListadePrecos(valor);
    gridView.DataBind()

**[UPDATE]**Código do método executar comando

public DataTable ExecutarComando()
        {
            if (_comando.CommandText == string.Empty)
                throw new Exception("Comando sem instrução SQL.");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                if (_conexao.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    _conexao.Open();

                MySqlDataReader dr = _comando.ExecuteReader();

                dt.Load(dr);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                if (_transacao != null)
                {
                    _transacao.Rollback();
                    _transacao = null;
                }

                if (_conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    _conexao.Close();

                throw new Exception("Mysql.ExecutarComando.", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_gerenciarConexaoAutomatica)
                    _conexao.Close();
            }

            return (dt);
        }
```

Comment: @Bacco o problema é assim, se eu fizer um **mysql.ExecutarComando().rows.count();** (método usado para contar as linhas do datatable), ele esta me retornando somente 1. Por este motivo acredito que o problema seja aqui talvez.

Comment: Perguntei pra ter uma visão mais completa da coisa toda, caso você estivesse usando algum loop. Essa mesmíssima query retorna vários resultados quando você testa manualmente? Experimente trocar o @CODIGO por um valor numérico já testado, diretamente no CommandText, em vez de usar o AddWithValue (apenas para teste, para ver se o problema está na atribuição ou no SQL).

Comment: Se funcionar com um valor hardcoded, dê uma espiada nisso aqui também, sobre AllowUserVariables (para aceitar @... ): http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,581862,581943#msg-581943 , pois de repente essa única linha sendo retornada é justo alguma com `med_cod = 0`.

Comment: Bom, vou testar aqui, o problema é que em outras consultas, funciona de boa o @... e na base de dados, testei hardcoded, com o valor da variável que está no @codigoMedico, e la retorna os 29 registros, porém qdo rodo a aplicação no Visual Studio, ele vem apenas o útlimo. Estou começando a acreditar que possa ser um bug do connector do MySql.

Comment: Quis dizer pra testar hardcoded no Visual Studio, pondo um comment na linha do `// mysql.Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue...` e trocando `and m.med_cod = @CODIGO` por `and m.med_cod = 12` (ponha um código existente na base). Assim dá pra cercar melhor o problema.

Comment: realizei o teste, não funcionou...

Comment: pode postar o código do mysql.ExecutarComando()?

Comment: @user2004054 adicionado

Comment: @Bacco adicionei mais detalhes de código na questão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente a função:
(Acho que não vai funcionar com os parâmetros. Não sei fazer com parâmetros, pois eu sempre forneço a SQL pronta, ou uso o Fluent NHibernate. Por enquando forneça a SQL pronta)

```
public DataTable ExecutarComando()
        {
            if (_comando.CommandText == string.Empty)
                throw new Exception("Comando sem instrução SQL.");

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                if (_conexao.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    _conexao.Open();    

                using (var MyDataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(_comando.CommandText, _conexao))
                {
                    MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt, "TABELA");
                }

                //MySqlDataReader dr = _comando.ExecuteReader();
                //dt.Load(dr);    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
                if (_transacao != null)
                {
                    _transacao.Rollback();
                    _transacao = null;
                }

                if (_conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    _conexao.Close();

                throw new Exception("Mysql.ExecutarComando.", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_gerenciarConexaoAutomatica)
                    _conexao.Close();
            }

            //return (dt);
            return (DS.Tables[0]);
        }
```